# Why my collision system isn't working properly?

Tags: c++, collision-detection, sfml

I am doing a game using SFML and the Tile System.
I am using this lib to parse my map and handle collision : 
https://github.com/fallahn/sfml-tmxloader

Basic detection works but the is a shift between my object position and my sprite collision.

When I am going to bottom and right direction collision works properly but when I am going top and left, there is a shift of ~2 tiles.

So I am guessign I am doing something wrong ..
When I am going forward, I do this :

```
else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Z))
{
    movement.y -= demonist->getSpeed();
    demonist->move(ACharacter::UP, movement, frameTime, map);
    noKeyWasPressed = false;
}
```

Then in my move method I check before doing anything if the point where I am going is valid.
So i enter my collision method

```
bool            ACharacter::collision(const sf::Vector2f& coord, const tmx::MapLoader& map) const
{
  const std::vector<tmx::MapLayer>& layers = map.GetLayers();
  sf::Vector2f tmp;

  std::cout << g_time.asSeconds() << std::endl;
  tmp.x = this->_x + (coord.x * g_time.asSeconds());
  tmp.y = this->_y + (coord.y * g_time.asSeconds());
  std::vector<sf::Vector2f> player;
  player.push_back(sf::Vector2f(0, 0));
  player.push_back(sf::Vector2f(0 , 82));
  player.push_back(sf::Vector2f(82, 0));
  player.push_back(sf::Vector2f(82, 82));
  std::cout << this->_x << " " << this->_y << std::endl;
  for(auto& layer : layers)
    if(layer.type == tmx::ObjectGroup)
      for(auto& obj : layer.objects)
        if(layer.name == "Objects")
          for(auto& point : player)
            if(obj.Contains(point + tmp))
                return (true);
  return (false);
}
```

`this-_x` and `this->_y` are the position of my sprite top left coordinate.
And frametime is the number of second elapsed since my main loop.
The size of my sprite is 82*82

Comment: My glass ball says it is because SFML puts the center point of shapes to the top left corner while your collision system puts the center point of shapes in the center. You can set the center point in SFML with `sf::Shape::setOrigin` to make it the same as your collision system and the offset will go away. My glass ball is known to occasionally be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by setting the origin of my sprite to the center of my image.  So the coordinate of my box became

```
  player.push_back(sf::Vector2f(-42, -42));
  player.push_back(sf::Vector2f(42 , -42));
  player.push_back(sf::Vector2f(42, 42));
  player.push_back(sf::Vector2f(-42, 42));
```